# How can I block wrong CSRF requests on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

When I make a request to my Rails app with a wrong CSRF token I get:

`WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

in the logs, but I want to block those requests, not get a warning.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* blocking the requests, after a fashion. After issuing that warning, Rails resets your session, thwarting the attempted CSRF attack.

You'll find restoring the original token will not restore your original session.

That said, if you really do want to change this behaviour, you would do so by writing your own version of the [`handle_unverified_request`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/handle_unverified_request) method to output an authorization error.

Comment: But how can I get the app to respond to the request with an unauthorized error?